# SF Short Story - Robots Carry On

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in the 1960s, although it may have been published earlier. English language, American or British author.
Two men, strangers, are talking in an office; one carries a cane. There is a large, bustling city outside the window. The man with the cane asks the other if he is a human being. The other replies of course he is. Man with the cane: you are actually a robot; we both are. The other: you are insane. The cane conceals a sword; the first man draws it and runs the other through the chest, pinning him to his chair. There is no blood and no pain; the other really is a robot. Now that he knows what he is, the other sees the world as it really is: the city is a blasted ruin and the human race is extinct. They are both part of a race of robots who have been programmed to believe that they are human beings and continue human society.

Comment: Can you remember if you read it in a compilation or by itself? Also, what kind of platform did you read this on. Physical book, magazine, online?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't make myself clear. I read it during the '60s, but I can't remember if it was in an anthology or a magazine.

Comment: Thanks! There was nothing wrong with your question, just wondering if you forgot a bit.

Comment: You've added a bounty, but you've not changed anything about the question. Are you certain that there's nothing else you can recall about it?

Comment: I wonder if it's the same as this (unanswered) story I asked ? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267593/short-story-blasted-earth-with-robot-avatars

Comment: Dear Danny: this sounds like a story I would be interested in, but it's not the one I'm looking for. If I remember correctly, my story takes place entirely in that one room.